# csv value seperator is not working properly

Tags: python, csv

```
csv_file = open("text.csv","w",encoding="utf-8_sig")
csv_file.write("Name,Author,Link,Price")
```

So result should be A column- Name B column- Author... But those all are at A column like this Name,Author,Link,Price. I am writing with pycharm, I checked CSV format value seperator is comma. And yeah row seperator ("\n") is working.

[image: CSV format]

Comment: You've just written a normal file. The result you describe is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Whats not working, you have a file and you write a string with commas in it. the result will be you will have a file with the line "Name,Author,Link,Price". So whats the issue

Comment: No in other pc everything works fine  OS windows 10. This problem occurred at macOS so maybe it's because of this or what

Comment: Yeah it's string but csv format splits new columns with "," and new rows with "\n"

Comment: you should use module `csv` or eventually `pandas.to_csv()` isntead of using only `open()`, `write()`, `close()` - and then it should resolve all problems with separators.

Comment: frankly I don't understand what is the problem - if you get line `Name,Author,Link,Price` in file then it is correct CSV - you should check file in any text editor to see what it created. Maybe you have problem only to correctly read it. OR maybe you added extra `" "` on this line `"Name,Author,Link,Price"` and then CVS treats it as single string.

Comment: I checked and it's because macOS uses ; delimeter in windows default delimeter is ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have just changed value seperator to semicolon wrote "Name;Author;Link;Price" and it worked. Because macOS uses ; as default delimeter